# 'Extreme high temperatures'- Is this usage correct?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, difference

I read an [article](https://phys.org/news/2017-02-extreme-high-temperatures-anu-expert.html) on climate change which used the expression 'extreme high temperature'

> Extreme high temperatures set to break records: ANU expert

I understand that 'extreme' can mean *extremely low* or *extremely high*. But since the article is using the word 'high', isn't the usage 'extreme high' redundant? So I figured that it must have been a typo, and that the author probably meant '***extremely*** high'. But just to be sure, I did a [Google search](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwirg6OD8KrUAhVFsI8KHfKjC9wQPAgD#q=%22extreme%20high%20temperatures%22&hl=en&start=0) and was surprised to find that this usage is quite common.

MWD defines 'extreme' as:

> a :  existing in a very high degree extreme poverty b :  going to great or exaggerated lengths :  radical went on an extreme diet c :  exceeding the ordinary, usual, or expected extreme weather conditions
>
> 2 archaic :  last
>
> 3 :  situated at the farthest possible point from a center the country's extreme north
>
> 4a :  most advanced or thoroughgoing the extreme political leftb :  maximum
>
> 5a :  of, relating to, or being an outdoor activity or a form of a sport (such as skiing) that involves an unusually high degree of physical risk extreme mountain biking down steep slopesb :  involved in an extreme sport an extreme snowboarder

Now, the 'extremely low' aspect is not given anywhere in this definition, but [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/extremely) does define it as

> Either of the two things situated at opposite ends of a range: the extremes of boiling and freezing.

What I want to know is whether the usage '**extreme** high' is correct, and if it is, how is it different from '**extremely** high'.

Thanks

Comment: In "Extremely high temperatures", the adverb _extremely_ modifies the adjective _high._ In "Extreme high temperatures", both adjectives modify the noun. Neither usage is "incorrect". Both convey the same meaning, and since a temperature can be "high" without being "extreme", I don't see a case for redundancy.

Comment: @P.E.Dant - You are right. The words 'high' and 'extreme' are not redundant. I did overlook the the point you made. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The context of your comment is likely a weather report.

Weather reports (in the US at least) use the term *high temperature* as a fixed phrase that is a shortcut for "highest expected temperature of the day."

If the high temperature for a day is itself abnormally or unusually high, *extreme* can be used to communicate that and it doesn't conflict with  the fixed phrase "high temperature."